# Double divide by 10 in java

Tags: java, double

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        double s = 253.3;
        while(s > 9) {
            s = s/10;
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Why the output is 2.5330000000000004 and not 2.533?

Comment: That kind of question is related to Numerical analysis which is studied by those who learn Informational Technology, Mathematics etc... Explaining that here I think is overkill. I suggest searching for that kind of books and reading them if you are interested! Even the answer from the provided link I think is not enough. I've spent one year at university learning such things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because floating point values are an approximation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: True, but doesn't really provide much insight.

Comment: Thank you. actually i do not know what to search, that is why i'm posting here. This [http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) also good!